# Why must a handler be defined for sigsuspend to return?

Tags: signals

I'm working on a school assignment where I'm sending signals between two processes. Process 1 sends a signal to process 2, and then process 2 sends SIGUSR1 back to process 1 to acknowledge the original signal.

In process 2, I use `sigsuspend` to wait for SIGUSR1, however, I notice this function blocks indefinitely if I never set up a handler for SIGUSR1. As soon as I configure a dummy handler, sigsuspend works fine.

So I'm curious, if I'm just using a signal as a waiting mechanism before proceeding, why is it necessary for me to define a dummy nandler?

Comment: You might want to provide a minimal code example showing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the POSIX standard [`sigsuspend`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html) is simply defined to only return if a signal not in `mask` is caught by a signal handler:

> The sigsuspend() function shall replace the current signal mask of the calling thread with the set of signals pointed to by sigmask and then suspend the thread until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process. […]
>
> If the action is to terminate the process then sigsuspend() shall never return. If the action is to execute a signal-catching function, then sigsuspend() shall return after the signal-catching function returns, with the signal mask restored to the set that existed prior to the sigsuspend() call.

Even with `sigsuspend` the normal signal dispositions for a signal are processed:

- an ignored signal doesn't interrupt the process normally, so it doesn't cause `sigsuspend` to return.
- an terminating signal terminates the process, so `sigsuspend` can't return.
- a signal with a handler causes the handler to run and then resumes programm execution, so `sigsuspend` can return after the handler finishes.

Normally (at least on Linux, FreeBSD and Mac OS X) `SIGUSR1` should terminate the process, so your process 2 should exit instead of indefinitely blocking. Did you perhaps use `signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN)` somewhere?